# No Driver package loaded message in google chrome webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpacker, uipath, webpack-style-loader

I am trying to automate a website using UiPath but I am getting the below message and not able to communicate with chrome. #webpack

**[OnContentScriptLoadRequest] No Driver package loaded**

Any idea why is driver not getting loaded? nad, which driver is it referring to?

here is the complete trace:

```
[BackgroundMain]
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [ClearExtensionError]
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [SetExtensionError] errType: NoError
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [StartNativeHost] nativeHostKey: com.uipath.chromenativemsg_v2
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [ConnectNativeHost] Created native messaging port with key: com.uipath.chromenativemsg_v2
2BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [OnNativeHostConnected]
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [RegisterAllWindowIds]
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [StartNativeHost] nativeHostKey: com.uipath.portable_host
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [ConnectNativeHost] Created native messaging port with key: com.uipath.portable_host
2BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [OnNativeHostConnected]
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [RegisterAllWindowIds] allWindows.length: 1
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [RegisterWindowId] windowId: 1
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [OnContentScriptLoadRequest] No Driver package loaded
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [OnNativeHostConnected] Received reply to RegisterAllWindowIds
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [RegisterWindowId] windowId: 50
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [OnContentScriptLoadRequest] No Driver package loaded
BackgroundMain.js:formatted:1245 [UnregisterWindowId] windowId: 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What version of the Google Chrome UiPath Extension are you using?